# shape of solid in 3 dimension

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I am confused in determining the limits of parameters of spherical coordinate system as i am not getting how will solid ask in question looks.question says'find volume of smaller wedge cut from a sphere of radius a by two planes that intersect along a diameter at an angle of 30 degrees.'please help me about the geometry of solid.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, your sphere and your wedge will look something like

[image]

Two planes, the two faces of the slice, meeting along the diameter, the top straight edge of the slice.

You know the volume of a sphere of radius $r$ equal $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$, all it might be there to do is to count how many wedges are there in a sphere.

Comment: +1 for the picture and the explanation! While the limits of $\phi$ ( or is it $\theta$?) are still unclear, we are getting some understanding..

Comment: thanks, but, what limits are you referring to? The azimuthal angle, in spherical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I guess the azimuthal angle is the one to put limits on.

Comment: thanks for the picture..and i think like this 6 wedges will get fitted in sphere so volume of one wedge will be 1/6 of volume of sphere

Comment: but if i want to do the sum by using spherical coordinates..i think this will work..divide that wedge into two pieces along x-z plane and take limits as 0<rho<a, 0<theta<(pi/2), (pi/3)<phi<(2*pi/3)and multiply that answer by 2 to get full volume..am i thinking right..?

Comment: Are you sure $6$ wedges will fit? For your integration, if you wish to split the wege in two as you suggest, $0 < r < a$ for the radius, $0 < \theta < \pi /2$ for the polar angle $\theta$ and for example $0 < \phi < \pi/6$ for the azimuthal (is it 30 degrees?), ya looks right to me, you can always check your answer with the first method

Comment: why you don't think 6 wedges will fit..as one wedge covering 60 degrees so there will be 6 such more...am i thinking right?

Comment: and if we take that wedge along x-y plane(symmetric about positive x-axis),then it will be at an angle of 60 degrees from z-axis(as it is cut by plane making an angle of 30 degrees with x-y plane)and cover the portion of that wedge by moving 60 degrees more so i think limits of azimuthal angle are 60 degrees to 120 degrees...is it right?

Comment: @omkar Girkar, well there might be a little ambiguity: by wedge, I would think they are referring to only one "slice", as depicted in the figure. The angle being 30 degrees, you could fit 12 of those over 360 degrees.Maybe, the description given could also be seen as taking two wedges: one slice as depicted and the symmetric with respect to the diameter, then yes, you would have 6. They says "smaller wedge" though. How do you see it?

Comment: Once the shape is understood,  the Integration Limits will follow suits. In general, please note that the only interesting limit is on the azimuthal coordinate, and all it matters is that the Integration is done between $ \alpha$ and  $\beta$, where $\beta - \alpha = $ the wedge ang´le you interested in. 60 to 120 or 3 to 63 is equivalent.